# commutator of product of subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading the proof of the theorem "every nilpotent group is weakly nilpotent"
from https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/41108/9/09_chapter%204.pdf, where it states that

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $G = HG'$, then 
$G' = H'[H,G']G''$.

(See theorem 4.2.3).

I unable to prove this and need help. 
Is it also true if $G=AB$, then $G'= A'[A,B]B'$?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to use the fact that $G'$ is normal. I think it comes out from the usual commutator identities, see number 3 of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator

Comment: @ancientmathematician Do those identities hold for the entire subgroups? or just elements?

Comment: @Rick  As stated, for elements, but you can soon extend them to subgroups.  I seem to remember that Marshall Halls book states subgroup versions

Comment: Then we can solve it directly through those identities, right?

Answer (score 1):

> In general, if $G=HK$ for some subgroups $H$ and $K$, then $G'=H'K'[H,K]$.

**Proof** (sketch) Firstly, observe that $[H,K] \unlhd G$: use that if $x,h \in H$ and $y,k \in K$, then $x^{-1}[h,k]x=[hx,k][k,x] \in [H,K]$ and similarly $y^{-1}[h,k]y=[y,h][h,ky] \in [H,K]$. To avoid tedious "administration" proceed to work in the quotient group $G/[H,K]$ and write $\overline{G}$ for this group. Note that $\overline{G}=\overline{H}\overline{K}$ and that $\overline{H}$ and $\overline{K}$ commute. This implies $\overline{G}'=\overline{H}'\overline{K}'$. From this the assertion easily follows.

**Note** In case $H$ and $K$ are both *abelian*, one can even show that $[H,K]$ is abelian, and hence $G''=1$ ($G$ is said to be *metabelian*). This cute little fact was discovered by [Noboru Ito in 1955](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN266833020_0062?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B404%5D%7D). If you can read German, you will appreciate the proof.