# $\left\langle A, B\right\rangle = A B [A,B]$ for every subgroups A, B of a same group. Can this be generalized?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $A, B$ subgroups of $G$. It is easy to prove that

$$\left\langle A, B\right\rangle = A B [A,B] \tag{1}$$

It has the following consequence : let us define a factorable group as a group $G$ wich has subroups $H$ and $K$ both $< G$ such that $G = H K$. Every solvable group with subgroups $H, K$ such that $H < G,\ K < G$  and $G = \left\langle H, K\right\rangle$ is factorable. (In particular, every solvable finite group which is not a cyclic p-group is factorable.)

My question is : Does there exist a formula similar to (1) for three subroups?
Of course, if $A, B, C$ are subgroups of a same group, we can write
$$\left\langle A, B, C \right\rangle = \left\langle\left\langle A, B\right\rangle, C\right\rangle = \left\langle A B [A,B], C\right\rangle = AB [A,B] C [AB [A,B],C]$$
but I cannot deduce a "beautiful" formula from it.

Comment: Indeed, the equation with two subgroups has a nice proof, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313957/commutator-of-product-of-subgroups?noredirect=1) on this site. It may be helpful for the case of three subgroups, too. But I don't know whether or not the expression can be much simplified (not to speak of "beautiful"). There are several commutator identities, e.g., [Hall-Witt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_subgroups_lemma#Proof_and_the_Hall.E2.80.93Witt_identity), which may be useful.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde
 Thanks for the link.